# Could not load file or assembly System.Management

Tags: c#, .net

I just installed Windows 8.1 (migrated from Win 7) and got the following error while building a solution that was working just before migration :

> Error 261 Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
>     BoggsSystems.Rocky.Shell

What could be causing this?  How can the cause be tracked down?

Comment: Have you expanded the reference-folder and checked for and exclamationmarks

Comment: Yes, and I just double checked in case my eyes were failing me.  It's a PRISM based solution and I went through all the references in each of the projects.

Comment: What was project's .net version.. .net 2.0 or ? Try to reload the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue: my build works fine on Windows 7, but fails on Windows 8. Also a PRISM based app (coincidence?) which targets .NET 4.

Solved by enabling the Windows feature ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)".

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue as well. It turned out that Windows Update updated some of it assemblies. This is how I solved my problem:

- Dropped the custom assembly from the db. This also dropped the assembly listed in the error
- I copied the assembly listed from the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 into the folder that contained my custom assembly
- I reloaded the custom assembly into the db. This also reloaded the assembly listed in the error